# Load .mat data in Python using Keras

Tags: python, matlab, keras

I want to run a neural network sample program on Python using Keras. My data is in the form of Matlab .mat file.

```
train_data.mat (size: 32x32x10,000 single)
train_label.mat (size: 1x10,000 single)
test_data.mat (size: 32x32x2,000 single)
test_label.mat (size: 1x2,000 single)
```

How can I load the .mat data above to replace the MNIST dataset in Python using Keras?

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
(train_data, train_label), (test_data, test_label) = mnist.load_data()
```

**EDIT (for illustration purpose)**

Let say my train_data in .mat has three data, with size 2x2x3,

```
val(:,:,1) =

     1     1
     1     1


val(:,:,2) =

     2     2
     2     2


val(:,:,3) =

     3     3
     3     3
```

It became below after loading with scipy.io.loadmat, with size (2L,2L,3L)

```
>>> A
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]]], dtype=uint8)
```

How to reshape it to (3L,2L,2L), which means three data of (2L,2L)?

**Answer**

```
>>> import scipy.io
>>> A = scipy.io.loadmat('train_data')
>>> B = A.flatten(1)  # flatten to vector
>>> C = B.reshape(3,2,2) # reshape

>>> C
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[2, 2],
        [2, 2]],

       [[3, 3],
        [3, 3]]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Krishna said, you can use `scipy.io.loadmat` to load matlab file as `numpy` arrays. Then you would have to reshape the data, for example, the `train_data` needs to be shaped as `(10000, 32, 32)`

However, if the matlab files you have are in v7, `scipy.io.loadmat` may give you an error. In that case, the mat files are actually in hdf5 format. You will need to use `h5py` to load the data.

Comment: scipy.io.loadmat didn't give any error, so it means the format is ok. But didn't manage to reshape it.

Answer (score 0):

you can read matfiles using `scipy.io.loadmat`. Please read the related documentation for details.

Comment: I've read it but I'm not sure how to reshape the data. Please see my edit.